# How to get and store images on different location - yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I have 3 environments on my server as:

```
1. PROD
2. PRE_PROD
3. TEST
```

The project developed in yii2 and its live. I have lot of images on `frontend/web/images` folder. Everytime when I want to compare both environments `PROD` and `PRE_PROD`, I have to make a copy of all images in both folder.

Is there any way to Upload and Show images from different URL like CDN. Means upload in a folder in `public_html/images` and use the same in all environment rather than from `frontend/web/images` of each.

Example :
I want this type of structure :

```
public_htmlimages

public_html/prod/
public_html/pre_prod/
public_html/test/
```

I want to write a code to upload all images in `pulic_html/images/` and refer from all available environment, is it possible?

Comment: if these are on the same server why not symlink image dir?

Comment: @cske : sorry, I actually don't know about symlink and how it works! Still yet, I am unable to figure it out!